# What does the prefix "on" in a function (e.g."onButtonPressed") mean?

Tags: naming, naming-standards

Sometimes I'll see some functions use "on" as a prefix, for example, on a button listener:

```
onButtonPressed();
```

and there are other examples:

```
onStateChanged();
onNotified();
onResume();
```

Does the prefix "on" have an implied semantic meaning behind it?

Comment: In this context, `on` <something> means `when` <something>. Please note that asking "*Why*" is `on` used in this way?" will probably be considered off-topic here.

Comment: Preposition of time like in 'on Sunday' or 'on Christmas'. Mostly 'on' is used only for specific dates but sometimes can be used together with more general events like 'on arrival'. So maybe slightly questionable grammar use here, but we have this often when naming things and try to keep it short.

Comment: its a prefix used to denote an event handler. On<Event Name> is an easily understood and grokkable terminology. IIRC it came to prominence with MFC and has stuck.

Answer (score 12):

Prefix "on" is most often used to indicate that method is intended to be used as a callback, i.e. not called directly, but set as a handler for some event.

For example, when you write method named `onClick`, you probably won't call it directly, but rather expect that GUI toolkit will call it once user clicks a button.

Comment: I wonder why the word "when" wasn't chosen instead. Apart from being used to the "on" idiom, "when" seems a little more obvious and clear - `whenStateChanged()`, `whenNotified()`, etc.

Comment: @jbyrd I think if you look at the 'tense' of the words it changes its use context for example; `whenStateChanged()` would be `onStateChange` and `whenNotified` becomes `onNotice`. It changes the context of the word and better describes the situation that will happen , not that it has happened. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Jessycormier - ah, that totally makes sense; thanks for the input! Also "on" happens to be half the letters as "when", so that's nice.

Comment: Natural language calls the construction ellipsis: Leaving out some of the words implied by the rest. Thus, "on Click" really means "*Called* On *Event* Click".

Answer (score 7):

**Edited** to qualify and expand my answer after the conversation in the comments with @MetaFight

---

In just about every language I've seen with events (JavaScript, ActionScript2/3) the `on` prefix is used to signify an event handler procedure and an `emit`, `fire`, or `raise` prefix is used on a method which elicits an event. (`On` might also be used in a property name to signify the attachment of a callback, such as in the `onclick` HTML attribute.)

C#, on the other hand, appears to break this this convention somewhat.

When the `On` prefix is used on a method in a base class, it will actually *fire* an event:

```
public class Base
{
    public delegate void OpeningEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event OpeningEventHandler Opening = delegate {};

    protected virtual void OnOpening(EventArgs e)
    {
        Opening(this, e);
    }
}
```

When this method is overridden in a derived class, the override is supposed to *handle* the event, also calling the base implementation:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    protected override void OnOpening(EventArgs e)
    {
        // handle event here
        base.OnOpening(e);
    }
}
```

This is presumably used to enable a deriving class to cancel propagation of the event (by not calling the base method).

From [the MSDN documentation for the `Form.Onload` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> ...
>
> The OnLoad method also allows derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. This is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class.
>
> Notes to Inheritors:
>
> When overriding OnLoad in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's OnLoad method so that registered delegates receive the event.

There's a [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18703490/225292).

Comment: Methods with the `On` prefix are typically event handlers.  On the other hand methods with the `Fire` or `Emit` prefixes are typically responsible for triggering an event **not handling them**.

Comment: In non-C# languages I'm sure that's true, but [C# uses the convention I've outlined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) where the event-_firing_ function begins with `On`. I agree it seems backwards, but that's the convention. My comment (and sorry if it wasn't clear) was that the firing function would be better prefixed with `Emit` or `Fire` (so I agree with you on that).

Comment: I just looked at the MSDN documentation for the WinForms `Form.OnLoad(...)` method.  To my surprise it *is* the responsibility of the base class implementation of this method to fire the related event.  Derived implementations are merely event handlers.  If you ask me that's a pretty inconsistent pattern.  And it explains the awkward naming.

Comment: @MetaFight Yeah, when I initially encountered the base-class convention it really threw me for a loop, having been used to `On` prefixing event _handlers_. I hadn't known the convention was to treat it as a handler in _derived_ classes (having mainly done base-class implementations in my C# work and only seeing examples of such). That is _quite_ awkward.

Comment: A bit nit-picky, but the convention belongs to .NET, not C#.  Those methods are available to other .NET languages.

Answer (score 3):

It's just one of the many meanings of the English word word "on", used as a preposition.  It indicates when the action occurs.  So `onButtonPressed()` is called when the button is pressed.

The function could be re-named `whenButtonPressed()`, but that's longer and not idiomatic

Answer (score 2):

"OnXXX" is typically something with events, but different platforms have different naming conventions, so the exact role depends on the language, which can get confusing.

In .net UI classes, a method name with the prefix "`On`" is a method which *causes* an event to be fired. For example, `Button.OnClick()` is the method which fires the `Click`-event. The `OnXXX` methods are protected, so it is only the object itself which can fire the events. This pattern holds for both web forms, windows forms and WPF.

But in asp.net web control markup, the attributes named `OnXXX` has a different meaning since they *registers* an event handler for the event. Eg. `OnClick="Btn1_Click"` registers the method `Btn1_Click` as a handler for the *Click* event. In other words the `OnClick` attribute on a web control does *not* correspond directly to the `OnClick` method. Rather it corresponds to the code `Click += Btn1_Click`. Honestly, this is somewhat confusing, and in XAML-markup the convention is changed, so the name of the attributes which attach events does not have the "On"-prefix but match the name of the event directly, eg.: `Click="Btn1_Click"`.

In JavaScript, the conventions are different. Here `onXXX` is the name of an event *handler*. Eg. `button.onclick` is a method which is called when the click event is fired (rather then a method which fires the event as in .net). The eventhandler atttributes in html are also named onXXX and attaches an eventhandler, eg. `onclick="handleClick()"` registers a handler for the `click` event (as in Asp.net).